# Batch script for copying and renaming files from a location to another

Tags: batch-file

I need batch script to copy just one file repeating every 1 hour, this file has the name `file_name_YYYY_MM_DD_hh_mm.csv`. The file exists in `Loc1Dir=C:\Users\abcde\Desktop\Practice_Folder\batch_rename\locatio‌​n1`
and has to be copied to `Loc2Dir=C:\Users\abcde\Desktop\Practice_Folder\batch_rename\locatio‌​n2` and then renamed to `file_name.csv` (removing the timestamp). I need that this file be overwritten everytime the file is copied to `Loc2Dir`.

I am currently using this script:

```
@ECHO ON

SET Loc1Dir=C:\Users\fgutierrez\Downloads
SET Loc2Dir=C:\Users\fgutierrez\Desktop\CrossCheck

CD /D "%Loc1Dir%" 
FOR /R %%F IN ("*_*.csv") DO CALL :copyFile %%~F %%~NXF
GOTO: EOF 

:copyFile
SET copyfname=%~1
SET fname=%~2 
SET fname=%fname:_=-%
ECHO F | XCOPY /Y /F "%copyfname%" "%Loc2Dir%\%fname%"
:::XCOPY /Y /F "%copyfname%" "%Loc2Dir%\"
:::REN "%copyfname%" "%fname%"
GOTO :EOF
```

It works fine, but it just replace the `_` in `file_name_YYYY_MM_DD_hh_mm.csv` for a `-` to be `file-name-YYYY-MM-DD-hh-mm.csv`

Any ideas?

Comment: **1).** If you want to copy just one file, then why are you doing a recursive search in the source folder by `FOR /R`? Do really want to copy all matching files from all subdirectories of the source and yet overwrite a single file in the destination path? please clarify the reason for recursive search. **2).** This is what `%fname:_=-%` does: replaces underscores `_` by hyphens `-` so the result you get in not unexpected. The question is why did you do that substitution? Do you want to replace `_` by `-` in addition to removing the time stamp?

Comment: sst, thanks a lot for taking the time to answer my request, at the end I resolve it by:                                                                                                
SET CCDIR=C:\Users\(username)\LocDir1
SET LOADDIR=C:\Users\(username)\LocDir2

move %LOADDIR%\*ticket_* %CCDIR%
ren %CCDIR%\*ticket_* ticket_search.csv                                                                       I don't know why I was complicating to much!!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to copy the very last incarnation of file_name_*.csv and strip the date time stamp you'll need two `for /f`, the 1st to get the newest date and the 2nd for the strip.

The choice of `file_name` as a place holder may be unwise. Assuming your actual name has also an underscore in between:

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\09\18\SO_52378446.cmd
@ECHO ON
SET "Loc1Dir=C:\Users\fgutierrez\Downloads"
SET "Loc2Dir=C:\Users\fgutierrez\Desktop\CrossCheck"

SET "FileName=file_name_*_*_*_*_*.csv"
SET "fname="

CD /D "%Loc1Dir%" 
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('Dir /B/O:N "%FileName%"') DO Set "fname=%%~nxF"
If defined fname For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=_" %%F in ("%fname%"
    ) DO Echo F|XCOPY /Y /F "%fname%" "%Loc2Dir%\%%F_%%G.csv"
```

The `For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=_" %%F in ("%fname%"` splits the found file name at the underscores and uses only the first two tokens for the destination file name.

Comment: LotPings, thanks a lot for taking the time to answer my request, at the end I resolve it by: SET CCDIR=C:\Users(username)\LocDir1 SET LOADDIR=C:\Users(username)\LocDir2 move %LOADDIR%*ticket_* %CCDIR% ren %CCDIR%*ticket_* ticket_search.csv I don't know why I was complicating to much!

Answer (score -1):

This will work:

```
@ECHO ON
SET Loc1Dir=C:\Users\fgutierrez\Downloads
SET Loc2Dir=C:\Users\fgutierrez\Desktop\CrossCheck
copy %Loc1Dir%\file_name*.csv %Loc2Dir%\file_name.csv
```

Comment: @LotPings yes it does. In MS-DOS and up including Windows 10.

Comment: Sorry, didn't look right. I'll remove my comment soon. But depending on the file system this won't neccessarily copy the newest file last.

Comment: Thanks Bernhard for the useful comments. Regards.